# How to block installation of new apps both from Google Play and from anywhere else IONIC?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Can anyone tell me how to ***block installation of new apps (both from Google
Play and from anywhere) by programatically level.***

For samsung, we can achieve this by using knox software.

Is it possible to achieve the same in ***programatically using IONIC***.

**Anyone help will be appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 0):

ionic is a framework in which we develop mobile applications. Do you want to block installation of other apps when your app is installed in the device? Not possible.

Comment: ok thank u. Is it possible by using any third party software?